# Install Ubuntu on a laptop with a pre-installed Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, ssd

I ordered an xps 15 l521x laptop.

It's embedded with a 500 go hardrive + a 32 go ssd m-sata. Windows 8 is pre-installed.

I'd like to install Ubuntu on to this laptop while retaining the pre-installed Windows.
I suppose that the SSD is already used by Windows.

I'd need to partition the SSD to install the Ubuntu on it too (only the '/' dir, '/home' and '/tmp' would go to the classical HDD)

Do you see any difficulties on doing it?

Answer (score 0):

No difficulty at all.

- [Make a gParted live CD/DVD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) (always handy to have one). You can also do this from Windows with Partition Magic.
- Resize the discs in such a way you like it and leave the created free space unallocated. You can do this with both the ssd and hdd but I expect it might be easier to put Ubuntu completely on the hdd.
- Install Ubuntu in the unallocated space

Result is a dual boot.